# QMessageLogger : Singleton for a Logger?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, singleton, qt5

I want to implement a logger for my application, therefore I created a class *MyAppLogger* derived from **QMessageLogger**.

Let assume I have several other classes implemented in my Qt **MyApp** Project:

- MainWidget : QWidget
- HelpDialog :QDialog
- CalculateNumers

How can I provide the Logger to all of those classes, without creating three Loggers? I would like to use *Singleton* mechanism.
But I've read that singletons would be a bad programming technique!?

[Here](http://ttp://www.file-upload.net/download-10772754/MyApp.zip.html) I just created a simple project with two empty dialogs. Then I have a MyAppLogger, which shall create formated strings like:

> [MyApp] info 12:12:00:123[ms]_12.12.2012) Object 'MyCalculator'created at 0xdeadbeef
>
> [MyApp] fatal 12:12:00:123[ms]_12.12.2012) Crash at function 'divisionDouble'

of cource with the required correct parameters (currentSystemTimeInMillis(), funtionname, etc, ...)

Example Logger, imagine there are lot of other classes, which should be able to use those void info(...), debug(...), critical(...), fatal(...); etc.
HEADER:

```
#ifndef MYAPPLOGGER_H
#define MYAPPLOGGER_H
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>

class MyAppLogger
{
public:
  MyAppLogger(QString outputFile);

  void info(char* expression);
  void debug(char* expression);
  void critical(char* expression);
  void fatal(char* expression);

private:
  QFile * _debugFile;
};
#endif // MYAPPLOGGER_H
```

and the corresponding SRC:

```
#include "myapplogger.h"

MyAppLogger::MyAppLogger(QString outputFile)
{
  _debugFile = new QFile(outputFile);
}

void MyAppLogger::critical(char *expression)
{
  QString line("[MyAPP] \t critical \t SYS_TIME (12:45:00_12.12.2012) :: ");
  line.append(expression);
  
  // write line to a file

  // write line to STD output 
}
```

Comment: Singletons have their uses. No one would want to pass a logger to every function or keep a reference to the logger in every class. But you don't have to go with a singleton, you could simply choose to instantiate only one, global logger. But you do have to be careful to ensure it gets created before anyone else tries to use it. Singleton can help with that.

Comment: Why do you need to override QMessageLogger? Usually it is enough to define static void action(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) and call qInstallMessageHandler(action);

Comment: @demonplus I there another example than http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler ?

Comment: Basically that is all what you need. Could you please share more details in your post what you are trying to do in your MyAppLogger ?

Comment: @demonplus Just edited the thread. I would like to have preformated output.

Comment: link seems to be broken and it is better to take essential parts of the code and post them here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see you want to achieve two things:

1. Change the output format of all logging output.
   You should consider using [qSetMessagePattern](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern) for that.
2. Write all logging output to a file:
   Subclassing QMessageLogger is not required. Simply use [qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) to install a custom handler and write the log messages to a file.

Using those two methods has the advantage that you can use qt's own debug macros (qDebug(), qFatal() ...) and you don't need to write your own MessageLogger or think about Singletons.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. Am i able to open an extra command window (cmd, shell) to display that out? If yes, how can I forward that Debugmessages to that commandline-shell ?

Comment: `qInstallMessageHandler` will return a pointer to the previous MessageHandler. In your handler code you can simply call the previous handler after/before you write the logmessage to file. That way you will see the output in the console of qtcreator or in the terminal.

Comment: Hi there, would it be possible to use this mechanism in order for the messages to be printed in a separated, low priority thread? I am worried about execution time, writing to a file can take a while. I would appreciate help.

Comment: @Lukasz Sure. Just save the messages away to a mutex protected vector and write that vector to a file from a different thread. On the other hand you may want to compile with QT_NO_DEBUG in release builds if you are concerned regarding performance.

Comment: @Dreamcooled Thank you for answer. But the point is I need those debug messages in release as well. I have wrote a simple singleton logging class and then I found about about `QMessageLogger` which is very powerfull and nearly ready to use. I was wondering about inheriting this class but I found this thread and your answers. So should thiss class be used for logging in a release as well?

Comment: @Lukasz I normally use this class for release logging as well. (Ok I'm not using this class directly but 'qDebug()', 'qWarning()' and so on - but they use this class internally)